# Assigining a negative value to a pixel

Tags: image, matlab, opencv, image-processing, pixel

Using some criterion, there are some pixels in the image which I'm not interested in. So, I would like to neglect them. I just want to ask if the approach I have followed is acceptable. I have assigned such pixels a negative value. Would that be acceptable? And, what does it mean when a pixel has a negative value? Will it have some representation on the image?

Comment: `I would like to neglect them.` you just neglect it and do operations on other pixels. Regarding setting neg pixels, yes you can if data type of image support it. but there is no point of looking for physical representation. pixel value denotes the intensity of that pixel, normally 0 being lowest (black) and 255 being highest(white) for a grayscale. So I think there is no point in asking what is intensity of a negative pixel.

Comment: since most images come with *unsigned* pixel types, that does not look feasible. but a couple of opencv operations allow you to specify a mask ( like the op is only applied where the mask is non-null)

Comment: Lots of examples of masking available, e.g. http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/38547-masking-out-image-area-using-binary-mask

Answer (score 5):

If your data type allows it, like signed integer (CV_32S) or floating point (CV_32F or CV_64F), it makes perfect sense to use negative values and it is a very common way to specify ignored pixels. In this case there is no special meaning to a negative value except your interpretation of it.

On the other hand, if you use 8-bit unsigned images (CV_8U), this may lead to errors : it may either be truncated to zero or converted to [0,255] using modulo-256 addition, depending on your version of opencv. In the worst case, it may also overflow to neighbor pixels and modify their values, if you access pixel data in a very bad way. So if you work with 8-bit images, you should rather use a mask to specify ignored pixels, as phyrox explained.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you use the image. A negative value in a pixel doesn't have any *real* representation. But if you use **Matlab** function `imshow(img,[])` it will scale all the values considering *-1* as the lowest number (so it will be represented in the output).

It is preferible to use a ***mask***. A mask is a binary array of the same size of the image that indicates if a pixel is valid (1) or not (0).

For example, in *OpenCV* there are a lot of functions that can use a mask (last argument `const CvArr* mask = NULL`).
Here you have an example on how to use a mask in OpenCV:

```
Mat srcImage; //RGB source image

//Create a mask. Here we select a rectangle:
Mat mask = Mat::zeros(srcImage.size(), CV_8U);  // type of mask is CV_8U
Mat roi(mask, cv::Rect(10,10,100,100));
roi = Scalar(255, 255, 255);

//Apply any function to the srcImage ONLY in the points selected by a mask
SurfFeatureDetector detector();
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector.detect(srcImage, keypoints, mask);     // passing `mask` as a parameter
```